# Center align WordPress Submenu

Tags: php, css, wordpress

How can I center align sub-menus of 'about us' and 'how it works' of propertycrowd(dot)com? Currently it's left aligned and I want it center.

**Screenshot**

[image]

I have tried numerous combinations but no luck so far.

Any relevant suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Dipak with css u can add `text-align: center ` and with padding u can fix the distance as u want.

Comment: @mimi As said, I already tried such combinations without any luck.

Comment: Dipak share ur codes plz.

Answer (score 1):

Try chaging:

```
#navigation ul ul
{
    margin-left: -25px !important;
}
```

to

```
#navigation ul ul
{
    margin-left: -10px !important;
}
```

Change the margin-left value as needed until it fits under the About us menu.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` for your `li` property.

```
  #navigation ul ul li
 {
   text-align:center;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added this element but what I want is to center align a sub-menu box rather than text. See this screenshot what I mean: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ec391h63b